# SharePoint Online Search Duplicate Crawled Properties Mapped

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search, crawled-property

Today we learned about the nasty MetadataExtractorTitle property that was messing up our search results. But it was only resolved after we found out we have 2 "Title" properties and 2 "MetadataExtractorTitle" properties.

See image

[image]

The top "Title" property was already set as well as a second "MetadataExtractorTitle" property at the bottom of the list.  The second "MetadataExtractorTitle" property was second.  Our issue resolved itself once we moved the second "Title" property to the second slot in the list.

My question is, what would the first Title property map to if it isn't the SP List item title? 
I can't seem to find any documentation that shows multiple Title properties. and nothing appears when I hover over it.